# Multiple Screen Support

Tags: java, android

I have some problem with multiple screen support, I work with dp(dpi) for specify the layout_heigth and layout_width and I hope that is the better way to support multiple screen, but when I tried with two smartphone I meet two different result.

I give an example, this is a layout I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/cities_main_layout"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

       <ListView
          android:id="@+id/citieslist"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="320dip"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:layout_below="@id/cities_main_layout"
       />

       <LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/cities_button_layout"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@id/citieslist"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">   
        <Button 
           android:id="@+id/bycountry"
           android:layout_height="50dip"
           android:layout_width="105dip"
           android:background="@drawable/buttonmarket"
           android:text="@string/button_bycountry"
          />
        <Button 
           android:id="@+id/top10"
           android:layout_height="50dip"
           android:layout_width="105dip"
           android:background="@drawable/buttonmarket"
           android:text="@string/button_top10"
          />
        <Button 
           android:id="@+id/recommended"
           android:layout_height="50dip"
           android:layout_width="105dip"
           android:background="@drawable/buttonmarket"
           android:text="@string/button_recommended"
          />

       </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The button are at the bottom of the layout, and I see two different result:

[http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/5513/htcmagicg2.png http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/5513/htcmagicg2.png](http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/5513/htcmagicg2.png)

[http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/6440/samsunggalaxys.png http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/6440/samsunggalaxys.png](http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/6440/samsunggalaxys.png)

In the last smartphone I can see the buttons, instead in the first I cannot...what's wrong?

I have to write a layout for any set of screen??!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ListView has

```
android:layout_height="320dip"
```

Now if the phone screen is smaller, it will not fit.

Try doing this instead:  (Edited due to comments. This is displayed correcty in eclipse)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relative"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/listview" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linlay">
</ListView>
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linlay"    
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thant should fix it I think.

Cheers

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to set the ListView to android:layout_height="fill_parent", as that means there will be no more place for the LinearLayout, that contains the buttons.

Comment: layout_height="fill_parent" in combination with layout_below on ListView and layout_alignParentBottom on LinearLayout is correct and should work

Comment: Yes, thank you Floarn. Although I forgot the below part, since he already added it himself, it will work.

Comment: I'm sorry to differ, but I've just tried the code in Eclipse, with all the indication you gave, and setting the layout_height="fill_parent" for the ListView, just make the List fill all the available space, no matter if you set the layout_alignParentBottom atribute for the LinearLayout.

Comment: actually you have to add android:layout_below="@+id/cities_button_layout" to the ListView, not to the button's LinLay ;)

Comment: It's possible to specify a percentage for each component?

Comment: @pedr0 Yes, it is possible, using a layout_weight attribut in a LinearLayout, as kcoppock wrote you in his answer.

Comment: your correction is better, but layout_above="@+id/linlay" should be layout_below="@+id/linlay"

Comment: I have somethings wrong in my code before, this solution work!Thanks, thanks and again thank!

Answer (score 1):

As others have indicated, your problem is that you hardwired in a size for the `ListView`. If you want a business rule of "have the buttons at the bottom and have the `ListView` fill up the rest", you actually need to write code that implements "have the buttons at the bottom and have the `ListView` fill up the rest".

There are two main approaches here:

1. Use a `LinearLayout` parent for the buttons and the `ListView`. Use
   `android:layout_height="0px"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` for the
   `ListView`. Use a regular `android:layout_height` for the buttons (presumably in their own `LinearLayout`) and no
   `android:layout_weight` for for them
2. Use a `RelativeLayout` parent for the buttons and the `ListView`.
   Define the buttons as having `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`.
   Define the `ListView` as having a`ndroid:layout_alignParentTop="true"`
   and `android:layout_above="..."`, where the `...` is the ID of the buttons' `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I am so sorry, but I didn't understand, what does it means "regular android:layout_height" in the first way you  have said me?Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I set android:layout_height="0px" for the ListView I can see the ListView...what's wrong?

Comment: @pedr0: I wrote "Use `android:layout_height="0px"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` for the `ListView`" -- you need to do both, not just part of it. Here is a sample layout (with a `WebView` and `Button` instead of your `ListView` and `LinearLayout` of buttons): https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/blob/master/24-WebKit/Patchy/res/layout/help.xml

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's because you are specifically declaring a height for your `ListView` and then laying the `LinearLayout` that holds your buttons at the bottom. Try changing it instead of being at the bottom of the `ListView` to something like

```
<LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/cities_button_layout"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:alignparentbottom="true"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
```

I'm not entirely sure if `align_parent_bottom` is the 100% correct spelling of that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, others have beaten me to it while I was typing, haha, but yeah, you're hardwiring a lot of things that shouldn't be, both the ListView and the Buttons. Take a look at this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cities_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >      
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/cities_button_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >   
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/bycountry"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonmarket"
            android:text="@string/button_bycountry"
            />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/top10"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonmarket"
            android:text="@string/button_top10"
            />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/recommended"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonmarket"
            android:text="@string/button_recommended"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/citieslist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/cities_button_layout"
        />           
</RelativeLayout>
```

1. You have `android:orientation` on your RelativeLayout, which isn't actually an attribute that RelativeLayout contains.
2. You should use the `layout_weight` attribute rather than hardwiring sizes for the Buttons. In my example, all buttons have a width of `fill_parent`, and a weight of 1. This makes them distribute the space evenly.
3. List the fixed button layout first, setting it to `alignParentBottom="true"`. Then set the ListView to fill_parent, and `layout_above` your button layout. This keeps the button layout at the bottom, and makes the ListView take all the space above your buttons.
4. Tada!

Comment: Are you sure there is any use to add android:layout_weight="1" to the ListView, as its parent is a RelativeLayout?

Comment: Not really, actually. I don't have access to Eclipse right now, I was going off memory. The layout_above should take care of it, the layout_weight is likely unnecessary.